# Access YouTube API without client_Secret

Tags: java, android, youtube-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am trying to use the YouTube Analytics API in an android app I'm writing but I'm stuck.
All of Google's documentation I've read says that I am required to use the client_secret when querying YouTube. However, when I registered my app with the APIs Console it did not give me a client_secret. 

[my API console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZjP5.png)
How do I access the API without the client_secret, as well how do I use the refresh token without the client_id. I have been working on this for 4 days now and I haven't been able to find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client secret is just an option in Android, you can use [AccountPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/AccountPicker.html)

In the [YouTube Direct Lite Sample project](https://code.google.com/p/ytd-android/), there is a [great example of usage](https://code.google.com/p/ytd-android/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/ytdl/MainActivity.java#290) you can check. It's using AccountPicker to pick account then authorizes though [GoogleAuthUtil](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I'll definitely take a good long look at those suggestions.

Comment: Thanks again! I got it working. AccountPicker is pretty awesome!